# Visual Studio 2019 creating loads of .tmp files

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've just noticed my project is creating tmp files inside the solution instead of using %temp% path from environment variables.

I checked the environment variables which are correct and pointing to the right folder.

Has anyone come across this issue or is there any setting within visual studio to change the path?

[image: visual studio solution folder]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue on my work computer. This is caused by our virus scanner (F-Secure). It can be solved if you put the file extensions in the scanner exclusion list. E.g. *.cs

Normally they are deleted automatically but I think the virus scanner have some kind of lock on the files and they are therefore not deleted.